# Logic Pro X Keyshortcut settings - can they be saved to iCloud Drive?

Tags: icloud, symlink, logic

how do I make sure that the Logic Pro X Keyshortcut settings are somehow fetched from the iCloud Drive every time?

I keep switching from machine1 to machine2 to machine3 and I think I've had to keep recreating the shortcuts from scratch about maybe 5-10 times over the course of the past 8 years.

Could Symlinked files somehow help with this?

According to Apple, the personal key command set is at **~/Music/Audio Music Apps/Key Commands**. Fingers crossed that this can be changed into a symlink.

Comment: It'd be great if Apple offered this as a regular feature and I didn't have to jump through hoops to get this to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is two-fold.

Here's part one.

1. Launch **Logic Pro X**.
2. Go to **Logic Pro X -> Key Commands -> Edit**
3. You will now see the Key Commands window. Click on the **Options** on the top-left corner of the window.
4. Choose **Export Key Commands** and save it to the **Music/Audio Music Apps/Key Commands** -folder.
5. Quit **Logic Pro X**.

Here's part two:

1. Now launch Finder and enter the **Music** -folder.
2. Locate the **Audio Music Apps** -folder.
3. Select it and Copy it to Clipboard.
4. Now, while in Finder, press **Cmd-Shift-I** to enter your **iCloud Drive**.
5. Paste the **Audio Music Apps** -folder there (or wherever on the iCloud Drive you would like to place it.
6. Wait till the whole folder and all of it's contents have been uploaded to the **iCloud Drive**.
7. Open the **Terminal**.
8. Navigate to **~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs** (use `TAB` to autocomplete **Mobile\ Documents**.)
9. Type **pwd**
10. Now type **cd ~/Music**
11. Type **open .** to open the **Music** -folder in Finder.
12. Delete the **Audio Music Apps** -folder.
13. Return back to the Terminal.
14. Type `cd ~/Music` to make sure you are there (just in case you started improvising and quit Terminal and are now in your home folder (~/)
15. Now type `ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs` - but when you type Mobile, press `TAB` to auto-complete **Mobile\ Documents**.
16. That's all, you can close Terminal.
17. You can now see that an **Alias Folder** for **Audio Music Apps** appeared in the **Music** -folder in Finder.
18. Launch **Logic Pro X**.
19. Go back to **Logic Pro X -> Key Commands -> Edit**
20. This time, select **Option -> Import Key Commands** and pick the keyboard shortcut file.
21. Verify that your customized keyboard settings have been accurately loaded.

From now on, your EXS24 Sampler settings, Keyboard shortcuts and other settings will be safely saved to iCloud Drive.